# Doubles from Wordpress Taxonomy Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am getting doubles from this wordpress query:

```
SELECT LEFT(main.post_title , 1) AS `character`,
            main.post_title AS title,
            main.post_content AS content,
            parent_data.name AS parent_title,
            root_data.name AS root_title,
            thumbnail_data.meta_value AS thumbnail_url,
            main.ID
        FROM wp_jlwx_posts AS main
            INNER JOIN wp_jlwx_term_relationships AS parent ON main.ID = parent.object_id
            INNER JOIN wp_jlwx_term_taxonomy AS parent_taxonomy ON parent.term_taxonomy_id = parent_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
            INNER JOIN wp_jlwx_terms AS parent_data ON parent_taxonomy.term_id = parent_data.term_id
            INNER JOIN wp_jlwx_term_taxonomy AS root_taxonomy ON parent_taxonomy.parent = root_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
            INNER JOIN wp_jlwx_terms AS root_data ON root_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = root_data.term_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_jlwx_postmeta AS linker    ON main.ID = linker.post_id AND linker.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
            LEFT JOIN wp_jlwx_postmeta AS thumbnail_data    ON linker.meta_value = thumbnail_data.post_id
            WHERE main.post_type = 'business' 
                AND main.post_status = 'publish'
                $search_where_clause
            $character_have_clause
            ORDER BY root_title, parent_title, title
```

This first thing that jumps out at me is that I am joining twice on the taxonomy table. How do I make sure that only one row returns for each row in the "main" table?

(Edit)
Ive been able to narrow this down to the thumbnail join where I am recieving extra data back from the meta table: e.g. a:5:{s:5:"width";i:960;s:6:"height"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive been able to find the issue:

Wordpress stores meta data when adding a thumbnail into the meta table.

The location is stored with the meta_key: _wp_attached_file wheras the extra data is stored with the meta_key: _wp_attachment_metadata.

So if I add meta_key = "_wp_attached_file" to the last join my issue is solved.